# The font size changes even though the css is not changed

Tags: html, css

When viewed on a viewport compatible device, if you delete one p tag, the font size will change to small and the sentence does not wrap. Why? The correct state is when the sentence are not wrapped.

[image: screenshot]

```html
<head>
  <!--1000px width-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000" />
  <!--1000px width-->
  <!--google font-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&amp;display=swap" />
  <!--google font-->


  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div>
      <p>----------------------------------------------------- 1000px wide text --------------------------------------------------</p>
      <p>----------------------------------------------------- 1000px wide text --------------------------------------------------</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess it is this line: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000" />`. 

Comment: When p tag is two,and p tag is one,I don't change viewport tag.The viewport is set in both case.

Comment: I'm guessing you are dealing with the feature of mobile browsers automatically adjusting text sizes in certain scenarios. If you don't like it, then turn it off: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Comment: By setting "text-size-adjust" and "-webkit-text-size-adjust", I was able to prevent the font size from increasing without permission, and text wrapping was no longer required. thank you.